# android - cast ToggleButton to subclass

Tags: java, android, casting

I might be misunderstanding type casting, but here is my problem.

I've got an Android View with a ToggleButton:

```
<LinearLayout
    ... >
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRec"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Start TEST"
        android:textOn="Stop TEST" />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in my activity I declare a ToggleButton variable:

```
private ToggleButton mRecordButton = null;
```

Now, I implement a subclass of ToggleButton, called RecordButton:

```
class RecordButton extends ToggleButton {

    OnCheckedChangeListener clicker = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        ...
    };

    public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        setOnCheckedChangeListener(clicker);
    }
}
```

And finally in `onCreate` I find the button by its id:

```
mRecordButton = (RecordButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRec);
```

This throws a `ClassCastException`.

Why? How can I cast it to `RecordButton` (the subclass) from `ToggleButton` (the superclass)?

Comment: why ? because in XML you declare a ToggleButton, which is not a RecordButton. Try declaring a RecordButton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your XML, replace the regular `ToogleButton` with the custom one..

```
<LinearLayout
... >
<package.class.RecordButton
    android:id="@+id/btnRec"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Start TEST"
    android:textOn="Stop TEST" />
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your views in layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    ... >
    <com.project.RecordButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRec"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Start TEST"
        android:textOn="Stop TEST" />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Eclipse with android SDK can automatically determine your views:

[image]